# Event Handling Between Two Classes

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, cardlayout

I have been searching for hours and still haven't found what I need, nor any tutorials/help guides/forums to point me in the right direction.

I have two separate classes that I need to implement an action listener. I'm able to go to one class from the other, but cannot figure out a way to get back to the main class. The main class is using a `CardLayout` to display the second class.

Is there any good tutorials, or any one that can help/give suggestions to this problem of mine? Thanks

What I have ended up with:
**Main Class -**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyGui extends JFrame {
    //CardLayout
    static CardLayout cardLayout;
    static JPanel cards = new JPanel();

    private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
        if(cmd.equals("HOME")) {
            cardLayout.show(cards, "Main GUI");
        }
    }

    //main Panel
    JPanel mainP = new JPanel();
    //north panel
    TitleBar tb = new TitleBar();
    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    //JLabel title = new JLabel("Title Bar", JLabel.CENTER);

    //center panel
    JButton widgetBox = new JButton("<--   Touch Screen Widget Area   -->");

    //east panel
    JPanel east = new JPanel();
    JPanel picPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
    JButton pic = new JButton("Pic goes here");
    JPanel settingsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JButton appButton = new JButton("Apps");
    JButton settingButton = new JButton("Settings");

    //south panel
    JPanel south = new JPanel();
    JTextField rssFeed = new JTextField("RSS FEED");

    //gui panels
    MyGui2 widgPanel;
    MyGui3 appPanel;
    MyGui4 setPanel;


    public MyGui() {        
        //main layout
        super();
        BorderLayout main = new BorderLayout();
        mainP.setLayout(main);

        //gui init
        widgPanel = new MyGui2();
        appPanel = new MyGui3();
        setPanel = new MyGui4();

        //CardLayout
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        cards.setLayout(cardLayout = new CardLayout());

        cards.add("Main GUI", mainP);
        cards.add("Settings GUI", setPanel);
        cards.add("App GUI", appPanel);
        cards.add("Widget GUI", widgPanel);
        cardLayout.show(cards, "Main GUI");
        contentPane.add(cards);

        //north panel
        BorderLayout header = new BorderLayout();
        top.setLayout(header);
        top.add(tb);
        mainP.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //center panel
        widgetBox.setEnabled(true);

        widgetBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Object source = evt.getSource();

                if(source == widgetBox) {
                    frame.setSize(325, 500);
                    cardLayout.show(cards, "Widget GUI");
                }
            }

        });
        mainP.add(widgetBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //east panel
        BoxLayout eastPanel = new BoxLayout(east, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        east.setLayout(eastPanel);
        picPanel.add(pic);
        pic.setEnabled(false);
        pic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rssFeed.setText("Add Picture");
            }

        }
        );
        picPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 150));

        //app button action
        settingsPanel.add(appButton);
        appButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //appPane
                Object source = evt.getSource();
                if(source == appButton) {
                    cardLayout.show(cards, "App GUI");
                }
            }
        });

        //settings button action
        settingsPanel.add(settingButton);
        settingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //setPane
                Object source = evt.getSource();
                if(source == settingButton) {
                    cardLayout.show(cards, "Settings GUI");
                }
            }
        });

        east.add(picPanel);
        east.add(settingsPanel);
        mainP.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //south panel
        BorderLayout footer = new BorderLayout();
        south.setLayout(footer);
        south.add(rssFeed);
        rssFeed.setEditable(false);
        rssFeed.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        mainP.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        //setLookAndFeel();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(500, 325);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
                    );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException exc) {
            //ignore error
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGui gui = new MyGui();
    }
}
```

**second class -**

```
bottom.setLayout(footer);
        bottom.add(homeButton);
            //home button action
        homeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Go Back Home");
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you thought of implementing observer/listener? more details could help, or better explanation on the problem

Comment: What is Second Class? How and where are you creating and calling its object in `Main` Class? Show the complete code for `Main` class

Comment: I've tried to use a listener, couldn't get that to work either. Basically, in my main class I am able to navigate to the other class(card) using the cardlayout, but not sure how to go back to the original card.

Comment: Second class is another gui/panel added as a card

Comment: did you implement the notify/update methods?

Comment: Nope. Can you point me to a tutorial about those? Oracles seems to only have "refreshers"

Comment: you can have an observable implement which is the one being watched, upon adding observers/listeners to it, and calling the method notifyObservers, every observer that was attached to the observable will be prompted: "HEY! IVE CHANGED!", in the observer implement theres a method named update which will be the prompted method, there you can do all kinds of things you want.

Comment: http://www.austintek.com/mvc/ is where i learnt it from

Comment: out of `MyGui2` , `MyGui3()` , `MyGui4` which one is `secondClass` in your code?

Comment: That's going to be the next thing I really study on next to events

Comment: MyGui2() is secondClass

Comment: Thanks. I learn something new everytime I'm here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method in `MyGui` that will direct the entire Application to the `Home` :

```
public static void showHome()
{
  cardLayout.show(cards, "Main GUI");
}
```

And within `SecondClass` use this method in `actionPerformed` as follows:

```
homeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        MyGui.showHome();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
In above code, there is still a bit of coupling between two classes.
There is another way out to achieve the same task and to eradicate the coupling issue:
Within `MyGui` while you are creating the `SecondClass` object pass the reference of `MyGui` current object to it as follows within constructor as follows:

```
public MyGui() {
...
widgPanel = new MyGui2(this);
....
}
```

Create non-static method `showHome` within `MyGui`:

```
public void showHome()
{
  cardLayout.show(cards, "Main GUI");
}
```

And change the `MyGui2` class as follows:

```
class MyGui2{
MyGui mg;//create an instance variable of MyGui

    MyGui2(MyGui mg)
    {
      this.mg = mg;
      //Do all other stuffs here.
    }
```

And within `actionPerformed` you can can proceed as follows:

```
homeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        mg.showHome();
    }
});
```

Comment: Introducing a static method is rarely a good idea. It increases the coupling between the two classes and makes it very hard to maintain and change the code.

Comment: @mariosangiorgio: Yes you are right.That's what I was contemplating. See my update. In this case it is not making much coupling..

Comment: Now it is better, but I'd go even further and remove completely the `static` keyword passing `cardLayout` to `SecondClass`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now have figure out how to return it to the original size

Comment: What has to be returned to original size?

Comment: when clicking home button on secondclass, stays in preferred size. but i can figure that out. Just had problems with going back. Thank you again

Comment: youll flood the stack with that mechanism, you never return from those methods, or did i miss something?

Comment: @Infested can you elaborate ?

Comment: @VishalK when do you return from the methods you gave here?

Comment: @Infested: What makes you think that those methods will never return?

Comment: @VishalK thats what im asking, i dont see where you return from them.

Comment: @Infested These methods are returning nothing (i.e. return type is void) then why it is needed to return anything? And if any method completes its execution it will automatically be returned...!

Comment: @VishalK yes, but where do they end their execution?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that `Second` has a reference to an instance of `Main` so that he can notify an event to it.